# Are radio buttons dead?

Tags: user-interface, checkbox, radio-button, usability

For the last several years it seems that radio buttons have practically disappeared. Selecting simple values for fields is easier by dropdowns (they are more compact), and even when the items to select are large, checkboxes (with radiobutton-like behavior) seem to be preferred.

Just now I wanted to make a feature for a grid (in a webpage) where you should be able to select a single row. Radiobuttons would be the appropriate element here (since only a single row is selectable, and one row must be selected at all times), but the instinct is to put a checkbox, because it seems more... appropriate and intuitive. It's like "selecting" has become synonymous with "ticking off", and a checkbox with its checkmark seems to be the right symbol for that.

Am I the only one with this sentiment, or are the radio buttons really on their way out? And what should I use?

Answer (score 4):

No, radiobuttons are not dead, they fill a very specific purpose. Checkboxes with radiobutton-like behavior are nothing more than evidence of bad design. If your instinct says to use a checkbox in your scenario, you need to study a bit more about usability to improve your instincts because your instincts are wrong.

Radiobuttons and checkboxes have very distinct meanings. Checkboxes mean "zero or more choices", radiobuttons mean "exactly one choice". If you use them in other ways, many of your users are guaranteed to be confused.

If your design requires and allows only one row to be selected at a time, use radiobuttons. Not *probably* should use radiobuttons. Not "go with your instinct". *Definitely* use radiobuttons. There is no gray area.

For one experts opinion on this matter, see Jakob Nielsen's article titled "[Checkboxes vs. Radio Buttons](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20040927.html)". It's from 2004 but still as relevant today as the day he wrote it.

Comment: I've run into situations where "zero or exactly one" is the intention, in which case - which do you use?  Checkboxes don't work because you aren't limiting choices, but radio buttons don't work either because you can't (in most cases) deselect.  For this, I think radio-like checkboxes make a sense if the radio-like part is within a larger field of non-radio checkboxes, but radio buttons with a "none of the above" is probably the correct answer in other cases.

Comment: @StuartBranham: yes, "none of the above" (or "undecided", for example) is the right choice when faced with "zero or exactly one" situations. You are still making exactly one choice out of a set of alternatives.